# Exception happens when trying to match on a RegEx

Tags: java, regex

I am not a RegEx expert and just rtying to debug some jUnit code that fails.

So if I am correct this is what we are passing in:

```
##ALT=<ID=DEL:ME:ALU,Description="Deletion of ALU element">
```

and this is the line of code that regex will throw exception, but don't have a deep knowledge of RegEx so I was wondering if you see something wrong with this expression?

```
pattern = Pattern.compile("((Description=\"[^\"]*\")>");
```

Than you.

Comment: What do you mean by regex will throw exception?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try:

```
pattern = Pattern.compile("((Description=\"[^\"]*\")>)");
```

In your case you could use something like this to matches against your string:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(".*(Description=\"[^\"]*\")>");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher("##ALT=<ID=DEL:ME:ALU,Description=\"Deletion of ALU element\">");
matcher.matches();
System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
```

This will print out: `Description="Deletion of ALU element"`

Comment: thanks, would you please a little more explain what is the difference between this one and the old one and what was that one missing?

Comment: the first escape char is for Java, and the second one will escape the quote for regex

Comment: looks like those `"` are to be taken literally in the regexp, this one certainly is: `[^"]`, and shouldn't be escaped. `"` isn't a special char in java regex and doesn't require escape in the context of the regexp

Comment: @FranciscoSpaeth : Thanks, but I tried it and still says unclosed group near index 26

Answer (score 2):

Your regex opens 2 `(` and closes just 1 `)`. That is incomplete. You have to close a group definition in your regex of it will fail probably with a parse exception.

Comment: thanks, will the fix to that look like what Francisco has suggested?

Comment: Ah I see... so should I just add another ")" next to the ")" that we already have?